# conditional operator works fine with one condition but not with other

Tags: terraform

I have a usageplan which i intend to either created or not created depending on the variable mantanance_mode which will have values true/false. The following code works fine.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "usageplan" {
  name  = "${var.environment}-usage-plan"
  count = "${var.mantanance_mode == true ? 1 : 0}"

  api_stages {
    api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id}"
    stage  = "${aws_api_gateway_stage.api_gateway_stage.stage_name}"
  }
}
```

but when i try to use it in the following way it just doesn't work.

```
security_group_id = "${var.mantanance_mode == true ? aws_security_group.allow_ssh_from_office_sg.id : aws_security_group.lambda_sg.id}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's worth using the conditional operator in the following way as described in the docs https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html instead of just using boolean true or false if you use `"some_value"` comparison it would definitely work.

```
security_group_id = "${var.mantanance_mode == "true" ? aws_security_group.allow_ssh_from_office_sg.id : aws_security_group.lambda_sg.id}"

resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "usageplan" {
  name  = "${var.environment}-usage-plan"
  count = "${var.mantanance_mode == "true" ? 1 : 0}"

  api_stages {
    api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id}"
    stage  = "${aws_api_gateway_stage.api_gateway_stage.stage_name}"
  }
}
```